# Converting an array to hash in python

Tags: python, arrays, hash, converters

Trying to convert an list to dictionary but could no get  expected output

```
p = {}
a = ["s","l","y"]
for s in a:
    p["size"] = s

print(p)
```

output:

```
{'size': 'y'}
```

but i am expecting output like this

```
{'size': 's','size': 'l','size': 'y'}
```

how could i acheive this in python

Comment: No it cant, `dict` key should be unique

Comment: Yeah that's just not going to work as itzmeontv said. What is it that you're trying to do with the data?

Comment: Suppose you have the dict `p` you're trying to create, and you do `p['size']`. What do you want to happen?

Comment: If my answer answered your question. Please think of accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve your goal since you are using a dictionary, and each key in a dictionary is unique. Perhaps you want to use a list instead:

```
p = []
a = ['s', 'l', 'y']
for s in a:
    p.append(('size',  s))

print(p)
```

Output:

```
[('size', 's'), ('size', 'l'), ('size', 'y')]
```

Comment: With this answer we converted a list into a list of nested tuples which doesn't match the dictionary as requested.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple same keys in a dictionary, so you can use a list of dictionaries. A simple list comprehension should do the trick.

```
p = [{'size': a_size} for a_size in a]
```

Result :

```
[{'size': 's'}, {'size': 'l'}, {'size': 'y'}]
```

Comment: You people should wait for a sec before down-voting anything. Let, the guy edit some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be a clean solution.

```
p = {}
a = ["s", "l","y"]
for s in a:
    if s == "s":
        p["small-size"] = s
    elif s == "l":
        p["large-size"] = s
    else:
        p["youth-size"] = s

print(p)
```

With the following output:

```
{'small-size': 's', 'large-size': 'l', 'youth-size': 'y'}
```